# Error Unmarshalling JSON without Root Element

Tags: json, jaxb

I have a RESTful web service that I am POSTing and PUTing `Entry` objects to. However, it is looking for a root element for the JSON and XML, such as:

```
{ "Entry": {
   "name": "John Doe",
   "phone_number": "555-1234",
    .
    . 
    .
}
```

However, based on examples I have seen using the `ContextResolver`, the `TelephoneBookEntry` root element shouldn't be required when reading in or returning `Entry` objects.

```
@Provider
@Produces({ APPLICATION.XML, APPLICATION.JSON })
public class JaxBEntryContextResolver implements ContextResovler<JAXBCONTEXT> {
    private static final Class<?>[] classes = {Entry.class};
    private static JAXBContext context;

    static {
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
        }
    }

    public JaxBEntryContextResolver() {
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
        JAXBContext ret = null;
        if(Arrays.asList(classes).contains(type)) {
           ret = context;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}         

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String phone_number;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I think my `ContextResolver` class is pretty standard, so I am not sure what is going wrong. I'd like to be able to POST JSON, or XMl, without needing the root element.

UPDATE: I've also tried without using `XmlRootElement, but this did not do anything. Also, I am using Jersey 2.17, so I'm not sure why unwrapping isn't happening by default.

Comment: what version of jersey is it ? New versions 2.x uses `jackson` or other JSON provider which will not look for root elements in JSON.

Comment: I'm using 2.17 @ulab

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the name of root element to XmlRootElement annotation

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TelephoneBookEntry")
```

Comment: I tried that but it is still looking for a root element to be present in the JSON or XML